# Strange listings syntax: emph=[<number>]{<identifier list>} or emph={[<number>]<identifier list>}?

Tags: listings, syntax, emphasis

In the documentation of listings (2015/06/04, Version 1.6) on p. 18 we see the example

```
\lstset{emph={square}, emphstyle=\color{red},
emph={[2]root,base}, emphstyle={[2]\color{blue}}
```

Note that the number `[2]` is placed AFTER the opening brace `{`.

On p. 31 we see, however,

```
emph=[<number>]{<identifier list>}
moreemph=[<number>]{<identifier list>}
deleteemph=[<number>]{<identifier list>}
emphstyle=[<number>]{<identifier list>}
```

Here, the `[<number>]` is placed BEFORE the opening brace `{`, a contradiction to the above example.

Which syntax is the "correct" one (with the usual caveat that "correct" is ill-defined, since there is only the code to compare against)?  If both are "correct": are there any differences in the semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual (page 27):

> Regarding the parameters, please keep in mind the following:
>
> [...]
>
> 2. You must put parameter braces around the whole value of a key if you use an [⟨optional argument⟩] of a key inside an optional
>      [⟨key=value list⟩]: `\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[one]two}].`

The brackets go in the braces if they are in brackets.

You can use this syntax even if not necessary, as is the case in your example:

```
\lstset{emph={square}, emphstyle=\color{red},
emph={[2]root,base}, emphstyle={[2]\color{blue}}
```

Or as the manual (page 19, emphasis mine) puts it:

> Note also that you must put braces around the value if you use an
>   optional argument of a key inside an optional argument of a
>   pretty-printing command. **Though it is not necessary, the following
>   example uses these braces.** They are typically forgotten when they
>   become necessary

---

What is going on here?

1. Arguments look like this: `⟨key⟩={⟨value⟩}`
2. You can drop the braces, if the value is a group: `⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩`
3. Optional arguments look like this: `key=[⟨optional argument⟩]{⟨value⟩}`
4. Again, you can drop (→ 2.) the braces: `key=[⟨optional argument⟩]⟨value⟩`
5. You have to put additional braces around the value if it is inside of an *optional argument*:
   5a. (→ 3.) `key={[⟨optional argument⟩]{⟨value⟩}}`
   5b. (→ 4.) `key={[⟨optional argument⟩]⟨value⟩}`

You **must** use either 5a or 5b if you are within an `optional argument`, i.e. in brackets `[]`.

Comment: @MdAyquassar you could also write `emph={[2]{root,base}},  emphstyle={[2]{\color{blue}}}`. It depends wether you´re in an `optional argument` (`[]`) or not.

Comment: @MdAyquassar Exactly. This is what the quoted passage and my elaborations in the answer are saying. From a pragmatical and syntactical point of view: If you are setting the options in brackets `[]`, than you *must* use the awkward syntax.